# Possible Reasons aspx Crystal Report Viewer would hang indefinately on IIS 7.5, under certain reports?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, iis-7.5

this is a bit of a shot in the dark but I am truly stuck here.

I have an asp.net MVC app that spits out some PDF reports. 
This works great on production Windows Server 2003 / IIS6, Local Dev Server, and Win 7 / IIS7

When I go to production IIS 7.5 / Server 2008, some reports hang indefinately without an error or a trace written. They just continue to spin seemingly forever, there is never a failed request back from the server.

Some reports do this, some do not, we've had multiple folks look at the reports and can find no discernable differences.

Does anyone have any tips on:
Why I never get an error/timeout?
Why some crystal reports would fail, and others are fine?

This works 100% fine in all other environments. I did some SQL tracing and the database commands are being run and terminating pretty much instantly, there is no hang there.

I have the 64 and 32 bit crystal runtime installed on the server. (Allow 32-bit is set to true for the app pool).

I have the same setup elsewhere and it works with no issues on Win 7 / IIS 7.

I've temporarily added the app user to Local Admins, and given him full access to both databases

Comment: Is it possible these reports were created with different default printers? When you run them on the server, they'll need those same print drivers installed. If they're not installed the server will hang on a "ghost dialog" prompting to install the driver. If it was db permission issue you'd get an error.

Comment: I'll check this out, thanks for any and all help here!

Comment: No problem, when this happened to me, I created a simple console app to `Load()` and close each ReportDocument. When I ran it on my server, I started seeing the "Install Printer" dialogs.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you so much! I've been beating my head against a wall on this for a week straight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per dotjoe's suggestion, a default printer that is not present on the system caused this issue. Make sure you a) have the printer installed on the server, or b) have "no printer" for default.

Thanks, Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Selected the printer 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer'.
To do this go to the report in the designer->Design->Page-Setup and select.